# Access data attribute from function made as property in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to pass data attribute to function that made ass attribute.

I have a button:

```
<button class="login-btn" type="button" name="button">Log in</button>
```

And some button handler:

```
$(".login-btn").modalForm(
    {formURL: "/login/",
     redirect: '/admin/}
 );
```

Modal form handler:

```
$.fn.modalForm = function (options) {
    var defaults = {
        // ...
        formURL: null,
    };

    var settings = $.extend(defaults, options);
    if (options.redirect != null) {
        settings.formURL = settings.formURL + '?redirect=' + options.redirect
    };

    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).click(function (event) {
            newForm(
                // ...
                settings.formURL
                // ...);
        });
    });
};
```

This works fine but i want to implement redirect as data attribute, something like:

```
<button class="login-btn" type="button" data-redirect="admin" name="button">Log in</button>
```

I've tried to modified button handler like:

```
$(".login-btn").modalForm(
    {formURL: "login",
     redirect: $(this).data("redirect")}
);
```

but it doesn't work. What is the best way to get param from data attr of button and pass it to my modalForm function?

Comment: Should consider why you need a redirect option if you are using attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify plugin code to work with a callback function or add an additional option to work based on an attribute(extract value from an attribute inside plugin code).

Plugin Code :

```
$.fn.modalForm = function(options) {
  return this.each(function() {
      var defaults = {
        // ...
        formURL: null,
      };

      var settings = $.extend(defaults, options);
      if (options.redirect != null) {
        if (typeof options.redirect === 'string')
          settings.formURL = settings.formURL + '?redirect=' + options.redirect
        else if (typeof options.redirect === 'function') {
          settings.formURL = settings.formURL + '?redirect=' + options.redirect.apply(this)
        }
      };

      $(this).click(function(event) {
          newForm(
            // ...
            settings.formURL
            // ...);
          });
      });
  });
}
```

CODE :

```
$(".login-btn").modalForm({
     formURL: "login",
     redirect: function() { return $(this).data("redirect"); }
});
```

---

If you don't have access to plugin code then iterate over the elements and initialize individually.

```
$(".login-btn").each(function(){
  $(this).modalForm({
     formURL: "login",
     redirect:  $(this).data("redirect"); 
  })
});
```

---

Or in case you just have one element then just use `$(".login-btn")` to get the element, get data attribute and set value.

```
$(".login-btn").modalForm({
  formURL: "login",
  redirect: $(".login-btn").data("redirect")
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `$(this)` to `$(".login-btn")`:

```
$(".login-btn").modalForm({
  formURL: "login",
  redirect: $(".login-btn").data("redirect")
});
```

When you call function `modalForm`, scope of `this` is not scope of `$(".login-btn")`. But, you can use `this` in `modalForm` function:

```
...
return this.each(function () { 
  $(this).click(function (event) {
     ...
     var redirect = $(this).data("redirect")
     ...
  });
});
```